# Get a clip of the image from when the text was recognized?

Tags: ios, swift

I have functtion for get CMSampleBuffer for camera and function recognizeTextHandler - handler when VNRecognizeTextRequest recognize text. I need to get image

```
 override func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
        request.recognitionLevel = .accurate
        request.usesLanguageCorrection = false
        request.regionOfInterest = regionOfInterest
        
           let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: textOrientation, options: [:])
        do {
            try requestHandler.perform([request])
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func recognizeTextHandler(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
   
    guard let results = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else {
        return
    }
    
    let maximumCandidates = 1
    
    for visionResult in results {
        guard let candidate = visionResult.topCandidates(maximumCandidates).first else { continue }
     //do somting
    }
```

Can I get a clip of the image in recognizeTextHandler from when the text was recognized?

Comment: Check the `boundingBoxForRange:error:`method available on `cadidate`, then its `bottomLeft`, `bottomRight` etc.https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrectangleobservation